# Extruding outward from center point to create the Bottle Cap Grip

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I have a bottle cap that I wanted to create the look of a grip by selecting every few other faces (having used the Select/Checker Deselect option to do that) as seen in the pic below. Now I'm stumped on how to extrude those faces outward from the center. Even better would be a way to round the edges slightly at the same time. [image]

Comment: There are many ways to approach any modeling task, but knowing what the end result needs to look like will influence what is suggested. if you are working from a reference you should include it in your question, preferably a close-up shot of the cap to allow more accurate suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Extrusion:

Way 1:
Select the faces, hit "e". Rightclick immediatly afterwards (that creates the extrusion but doesn't move it). Then hit "s" and "shift z" and move the mouse to scale them outwards.

Way 2:
Hit "i". Move the mouse to scale the new faces the same size as the original one. Now press & hold "ctrl" and move the mouse.

2. Further adjustment (optional)
   Set "individual origins" and hit "s" to scale them smaller
3. Bevel
   Hit "ctrl + b" to bevel them, use mouse drag + mouse wheel to adjust number of steps (roundness) and shape.

[image: gif]

Answer (score 6):

After checker deselect use the [Inset Tool](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html?highlight=inset) <kbd>I</kbd>. To extrude the faces and also make them new faces a bit smaller.

Then add a subsurf modifier with two subdivisions <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>2.

And make the object use smooth shading.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set individual origins as pivot point:

[image]

after that you can extrude along the normals

[image]

Comment: Close.. but I need it to have the faces on either side also extrude with each face so it's not so abrupt and more slanted outward.

Answer (score 1):

Based off of currently selected faces from your image:

1. Hit NUM7
2. Set Pivot Point to **Individual Faces**
3. Press R and rotate all the faces to the preferred angle. (To create the ridges like a water bottle.)

Reference Picture:[image]

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> moves something along it's normal. If you have several items selected, they will move according to their own normal. Think it makes the selection fatter or slimmer.

So select the desired geometry and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Move the mouse up and down. It looks like this:

[image: shrinked faces]