# How to create this lid with ridged grip

Tags: modeling, mesh

How do I create this bottle lid with grooves on a ridged grip.

A kind of jar cap with a ribbed texture.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43883/extruding-outward-from-center-point-to-create-the-bottle-cap-grip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could model one (mirrored) segment of your object:

[image]

Array it with the *Array* modifier:

[image]

Bend it with the *Simple Deform* modifier (*Bend* mode, 360° on Z):

[image]

Modify the topology to make it look the way you want:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Rounder topology:

[image]